# Check if a word is buildable by defined parts in an array

Tags: c#

My goal is to create a function in C#, which checks whether a word is combinable through defined parts.

For example:

```
string parts[] = new String[] {"ca", "c", "a", "t", "mo" "u" "s"};
```

An input of `stringToTest = "Cat";` would result an `buildable=true` but `stringToTest = "Mouse";` would not, because of the missing 'e' in the array.

Additionally, the function should return the array indexes where the blocks are located, for example with `cat` the result should return index positions of 0,2,3

Also, it would be a goal to use the biggest possible parts that are available, for example `cat` could be build by the specified characters `c,a,t` respectively index `1,2,3` but could also build by less option, when using the characters `ca,t` respective index `1,3`

What would be the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Is it OK to reuse parts? That is, can `java` be built from `j, a, v`?

Comment: You only specify (incompletely) your requirement without any own effort and also don't respond to questions or people trying to find a solution like kshkarin. Voting to close because it "needs more focus".

Answer (score 1):

Solution will find the word and with as less parts of the `string[]` as possible, it'll print out the parts and the index they're found.

EDIT: Modified and corrected, see @TimSchmelter comment for an explanation of the mistake found previously.

DotNetFiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/MeUpAS

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var parts = new String[]{"ca", "c", "a", "t", "mo", "u", "s"};
        var test = "cactus";
        var results = new List<string>();
        var isFound = false;
        
        var temp = String.Copy(test);
        foreach (string part in parts.OrderByDescending(p => p.Length))
        {
            if (temp.Contains(part))
            {
                temp = temp.Remove(temp.IndexOf(part), part.Length);
                results.Add(part);
                if (String.Join(string.Empty, results).ToCharArray().Except(test.ToCharArray()).Any() == false
                   && String.Join(string.Empty, results).Length == test.Length)
                {
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isFound)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success, found the test string \"{0}\" in the array", test);
            
            foreach (string result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result part: {0}\t Result index: {1}", result, Array.IndexOf(parts, result));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure, test string not found in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This just works with the "cat" sample. If you search for "sumo" it will fail. Reason is that you don't iterate all possible combinations but just once from left to right.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you're absolutely correct, still fiddling with it after that realization...

Comment: after you found a matching part you need to start with part 1 again for the next substring.

Comment: @TimSchmelter trimmed the string from the part result, compared char arrays and lengths of result to the string being tested

Comment: interesting approach, how you manage to avoid multiple iterations. But you might still have an issue. I guess that "momo" should succeed because "mo" is contained and i assume that it can be used multiple times.

Comment: @TimSchmelter technically the assumption is without repeating anything from parts array, so "momo" would fail - you can test it from the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MeUpAS).

Comment: Yes, i saw that it would fail and i doubt that this is desired. But OP also didn't specify it. +1 for your efforts